# Access the subscribers functionality in the salesforce community

Tags: customer-community, lma, subscriber

I want to access the subscribers functionality on the **community** which is used by the **Licence Management App** by a visualforce page.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page >

   <script>
     function srcUp(url) { window.open(url, '_blank'); }
   </script>

   <apex:include pageName="{!URLFOR('/partnerbt/lmo/subOrgLogin.apexp')}">
   </apex:include>

</apex:page>
```

If I use this functionality on the community then it is giving me `insufficient error`.

The work I have done is that I have created a lightning component and access the page into iframe.